# User session between Express+Nodejs and clients using Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, session, firebase-authentication

what's a common approach of storing user sessions with Nodejs+Express and Firebase auth? I have Android and Ios app that I'd like to use the same logic on (later web as well), so I'd get the JWT token. I'd like to use that token as authorization for requests. Also I'd like to keep the user sessio and not require them to relogin again. I am not sure how to go about this, all of the Express Session resources I've found were on topic of web and cookies. I've stumbled [upon MongoConnection a library for Express](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo) that presumably stores the sessions in the MongoDb, but how does the session work with non-web requests? Can anyone help me clarify this, I am aware that I am missing the point here as there is certainly an easy way to verify incoming requests and also have a session for the user to not have to login everytime.

Preferably I'd like to have an easy way to have endpoints that require JWT token access. Besides that also have a session of sorts. There is a function to verify tokens in the Firebase Admin SDK for Nodejs but it seems really weird to have to check the token manually in every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I treat sessions on the backend and front end entirely separately as I predominantly make RESTful apis. On the front end you can handle sessions however you like, e.g. you can start a session when a user authenticates with firebase auth, and set the user role maybe based of attributes on the firebase auth user. Use cookies, do whatever you prefer.

Then on the backend, on every endpoint just decode the token, verify it, check that the user has access to the resource they are requesting etc. Its common to write your own middlewares so that you dont have to repeat the decoding code. For further info on this approach, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) might help. Its not weird to check the token manually on every request, its common practice to guarantee the authenticity of the request. Hope this is of some help.

To sum up, treat your front end session entirely separately from the backend. On your express server on the backend, on any protected endpoint decode and verify the token to determine if the user has access to the resource.

Backend sessions with firebase are a bad idea (due to it been serverless), its better to create a stateless restful api.

Comment: So basically staying logged in should be handled on the frontend and then in the backend I'd have to write my own middleware to verify requests (or do it manually everytime)? I dont have firebase serverless backend but rather a hosted nodejs server

Comment: Thats exactly it yes. Ah gotcha, I would still recommend not having sessions on the backend and making it stateless personally.